# Applying Pipeline and Nested Cross validation partly manually with RFECV and GridSearch

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation, feature-selection

I am trying to implement nested cross validation in a bit more manual way than using `GridSearchCV` within a `cross_val_score`, so I can have a bit more control of what I am doing, account for data leakage, see how my vars and hyperparameters are changing along the way and keep a record of them, and also to understand more clearly how everything is working.

I would like to ask if this implementation below looks good to you.

### Processing Pipelines: Data Leakage

#### Categorical Variables

```
cat_pipe = Pipeline([("encoder",OneHotEncoder(drop="first"))])
```

#### numerical features that could be categorical

```
num_pipe = Pipeline([("encoder",OneHotEncoder(drop="first"))])
```

#### Continious variables

```
num_cont_pipe = Pipeline([("scaler",StandardScaler())])

preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('cat', cat_pipe, cat_var),
                                               ('num', num_pipe, num_cat_vars), "num_cont",num_cont_pipe,num_cont)],n_jobs=-1)#,sparse_threshold=0)
```

### Nested Cross Validation

```
cv_outer = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=5, random_state=0)
cv_inner = StratifiedKFold(n_splits=10,random_state=0) # RepeatedStratifiedKFold(n_repeats=3,n_splits=10,random_state=0)
```

### Estimator and model

```
estimator = RandomForestClassifier(class_weight="balanced")
model = XGBClassifier(eval_metric="logloss")
```

### Feature Selection and Hyperparameter Optimization

```
rfe = RFECV(estimator,cv=cv_inner, scoring="roc_auc",n_jobs=-1)
```

### Implementation

```
for train_ix, test_ix in cv_outer.split(X,y):
    time_start_outer = time.time()

    X_train = X.iloc[train_ix,:]
    X_test = X.iloc[test_ix,:]
    y_train = y.iloc[train_ix]
    y_test = y.iloc[test_ix]


    # Data Prep
    X_train_enc = preprocessor.fit_transform(X_train)
    X_test_enc = preprocessor.transform(X_test)

        
    # Feature Selection
    X_train_enc_var = rfe.fit(X_train_enc,y_train)
    print(f"The number of features selected is {X_train_enc_var.n_features_}", sep="/n")
    X_train_enc_var = rfe.transform(X_train_enc)
    X_test_enc_var = rfe.transform(X_test_enc)

    # Hyperparameter tuning 
    counter = Counter(y_train)
    weight = counter[0] / counter[1]
    hyper_params = {
        # XGBClassifier
        "scale_pos_weight":[1,2,3,4,5,6,weight,7,8,9,10,11,12]
        }

    grid_search = GridSearchCV(model,cv=cv_inner,param_grid=hyper_params,n_jobs=-1,scoring="roc_auc")
    X_train_enc_var_hyp = grid_search.fit(X_train_enc_var,y_train)

    best_model = X_train_enc_var_hyp.best_estimator_

    yhat = best_model.predict(X_test_enc_var)
    # evaluate the model
    score = roc_auc_score(y_test, yhat)

    # store the result
    outer_results.append(score)
    outer_params.append(X_train_enc_var_hyp.best_params_)

    # report progress
    print(f' test_score= {score}, validation_score= {X_train_enc_var_hyp.best_score_}')


# summarize the estimated performance of the model
print(f'best_score: {np.mean(outer_results)}, {np.std(outer_results)}')
```

Comment: Thanks, what do you think of the implementation so far?

Comment: From a very first look, cannot find anything profoundly wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I noticed three things.

First, not important:

```py
    # Feature Selection
    X_train_enc_var = rfe.fit(X_train_enc,y_train)
    print(f"The number of features selected is {X_train_enc_var.n_features_}", sep="/n")
    X_train_enc_var = rfe.transform(X_train_enc)
    X_test_enc_var = rfe.transform(X_test_enc)
```

You save the fitted `rfe` out to `X_train_enc_var`, and then two lines later overwrite that as a transformed dataset.  This all works out the way you want, but maybe to be more honest to the variable names:

```py
    X_train_enc_var = rfe.fit_transform(X_train_enc,y_train)
    X_test_enc_var = rfe.transform(X_test_enc)
    print(f"The number of features selected is {rfe.n_features_}", sep="/n")
```

Second, you use the same `cv_inner` for, separately, the recursive feature elimination and the grid search.  This means the number of features selected has information from the (inner) test folds, and so the grid search scores may be optimistically biased.  That's probably not a big deal, because you only care about relative scores for the search.  But *maybe* some hyperparameter combination would do a better job with a different number of features, and so gets penalized.

Finally, most serious but also easiest to fix: you call `best_model.predict(...)`, but since you're taking the `roc_auc_score`, you will want instead `best_model.predict_proba(...)[:, 1]` for the probability scores (for the positive class).

One other suggestion: since you're going through a lot of computation, save some more information: the rfe's `grid_scores_`, the grid search's `cv_results_` for example.

Comment: Hello @ben-reiniger. Thank you so much for all your observations, that are very useful. The only thing I couldn't quite get is the second suggestion. At the moment I am using the  `cv_inner` to split the  training data only to avoid precisely that, optimistic bias, but maybe you mean that I should combine the `cv_inner` for the `RFECV` and `GridseachCV` rather than use them separately?

Comment: To be perfectly legitimate, the RFECV should happen on yet another layer of nesting, splitting the training folds from the search's CV.  Of course then computations will be even longer.  Maybe consider `SelectKBest` and let the grid search over `k`?

Comment: Hi Ben, sorry for being so hard headed, but I am still not quite sure what you mean, so you mean to create a `cv_inner_two` kind of thing for the `RFECV` or you mean to use it embedded into the `GridSearchCV`?

Comment: The former is what I was getting at.  I think the latter could also work, but it may depend on how exactly you set it up.  If you don't need the per-fold `RFECV` results, you could just use an integer `cv` for that, and put it in a `pipeline` with `model` inside the search.